# When do parametric equations constitute a line?

Tags: vectors

The given equations specifically are

$x=3t^3 + 7$
$y=2-t^3$
$z=5t^3 + 3$

And

$x=5t^2-1$
$y=2t^2 + 3$
$z=1-t^2$

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Whether the systems of equations describe a straight line?

Comment: take a little view at [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametricplot3d+%7B3t%5E3%2B7%2C+2%E2%88%92t%5E3%2C+5t%5E3%2B3%7D]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first case, $r=(7,2,3)+t^3(3,-1,5)$. As $t$ varies through $\mathbb R$, $t^3$ varies through $\mathbb R$, so we have a line.

For the second case, $r=(-1,3,1)+t^2(5,2,-1)$. As $t$ varies through $\mathbb R$, $t^2$ varies through the non-negative reals, so we have a ray.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to see this.  Firstly you can solve each $t^3$ in terms of $x,y$ and $z$, and have a line in terms of its symmetric equation.

You could also re-parameterize these by making the substitution $u = t^3$, and you can see it must be a line in that case.

Incidentally, the second equation is a ray, not a line.  That is because $t^2$ only takes positive values.